# What does it mean for a vector field to preserve area?

Tags: vector-analysis, hamilton-equations

I was reading a book about hamiltonian mechanics. After computing the divergence of the hamiltonian vector field to be identically zero, the author adds:
"...thus the vector field is divergence-free and its flow preserves area in the phase plane."
What does it mean to preserve area? I just couldn't see the area here..

Comment: you didn't see the **in phase space**?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) should be related.

Answer (score 4):

It means that the flow of the vector field is an area-preserving map (for each $t$). That is, if you take any region in the phase plane, and let its points “go with the flow” for a certain time $t$, they will then form a new region whose area is the same as the area of the original region.

Comment: Can you point to some source with mathematical implementation??

Comment: @GarvitaTiwari: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by a "mathematical implementation".